# How can I create links to an item in a collapsed accordion?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-ui-accordion

Attempting to create links into a page that contains collapsed accordion items, each identified by div ID numbers.

Failed attempts to link and open specific items by adding parameters to my links look like:

```
sample.html#itemIdX  // opens to the page but not the item

sample.html?itemIdX  // same result
```

The items use an `H3` class:

```
itemPreviewTitle accordionHeader ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" style="zoom: 1;
```

How do I create a link that makes my itemX have an expanded state?

Comment: Did you have any luck applying the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bit trickier than it seems, as the [Accordion API docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) are not all that easy to follow, and the `activate()` function doesn't appear to work as advertised.

From your question, it sounds like you want to open an accordion section by referencing a div ID. This isn't possible out of the box; you can only identify sections using a 0-based index (e.g. 0 = first section, 1 = second section, etc.).

Having said that, this approach will work:

Define the links like this:

```
<a href="10387904_Accordion_link_2.html?openAccordionId=0">Open first item</a>
<a href="10387904_Accordion_link_2.html?openAccordionId=1">Open second item</a>
<a href="10387904_Accordion_link_2.html?openAccordionId=2">Open third item</a>
```

On the page containing the accordion, use the following code to extract the ID from the query string and initialise the accordion with the relevant section activated:

```
// Using the parseQueryString extension from
// http://paulgueller.com/2011/04/26/parse-the-querystring-with-jquery/
$.extend({
    parseQuerystring: function () {
        var nvpair = {};
        var qs = window.location.search.replace('?', '');
        var pairs = qs.split('&');
        $.each(pairs, function (i, v) {
            var pair = v.split('=');
            nvpair[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        });
        return nvpair;
    }
});

// Get the index of the section we want to open from the querystring.
var openAccordionId = parseInt($.parseQuerystring()["openAccordionId"]);

// Initialise the accordion with the active section defined.
var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion({ active: openAccordionId });

// Note: for some reason, the following does not work:
//  var accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
//  accordion.activate(openAccordionId);
```